# Pandas: combine two dataframes with same columns by picking values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

The first:

```
id  time_begin  time_end
0   1938    1946
1   1991    1991
2   1359    1991
4   1804    1937
6   1368    1949
... ... ...
```

Second:

```
id  time_begin  time_end
1   1946    1946
3   1940    1954
5   1804    1925
6   1978    1978
7   1912    1949
```

Now, I want to combine the two dataframes in such a way that I get all rows from both. But since sometimes the row will be present in both dataframes (e.g. row 1 and 6), I want to pick the minimum time_begin of the two, and the maximum time_end for the two. Thus my expected result:

```
id  time_begin  time_end
0   1938    1946
1   1946    1991
2   1359    1991
3   1940    1954
5   1804    1925
4   1804    1937
6   1368    1978
7   1912    1949
... ... ...
```

How can I achieve this? Normal join/combine operations do not allow for this as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the dataframes and then use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) in order to pick min(time_begin) and max(time_end)

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'id':[0,1,2,4,6],'time_begin':[1938,1991,1359,1804,1368],'time_end': 
                       [1946,1991,1991,1937,1949]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,3,5,6,7],'time_begin':[1946,1940,1804,1978,1912],'time_end': 
                       [1946,1954,1925,1978,1949]})

#merge
df=df1.merge(df2,how='outer') 
#groupby
df=df.groupby('id').agg({'time_begin':'min','time_end':'max'})
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to define different aggregation functions per column:

```py
pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('id').agg({'time_begin':'min', 'time_end':'max'})
```